# Adding "th", "nd" or "rd" to a date in C

Tags: c

I'm modifying some driver software for my keyboard and part of it is a plugin that outputs the date to my keyboard screen. At the moment it says 1 January but I really want it to say 1st, 2nd, 3rd or 4th or whatever.

I've been looking everywhere for some kind of code that will give me some kind of an idea on how to do it but I can only find examples for C# and I'm using C.

Edit:

```
const char *ordinals[] = {"", "1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "5th", "6th", "7th", "8th", "9th", "10th", "11th", "12th", "13th", "14th", "15th", "16th", "17th", "18th", "19th", "20th", "21st", "22nd", "23rd", "24th", "25th", "26th", "27th", "28th", "29th", "30th", "31st"};

sprintf(date, "%s %s", ordinals[t->tm_mday], mon);
```

Comment: Make that `ordinals[t->tm_mday]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you need this only for numbers `1` through `31`, the easiest approach is to define an array of ordinals, like this:

```
const char *ordinals[] = {"", "1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th"..., "31st"};
...
printf("%s of %s", ordinals[dayNumber], monthName);
```

This is better than doing it algorithmically, because it is more readable, and is easier to internationalize, should you run into this at some point later on.

Comment: Excellent, O(1) time, and readable. But what's the first empty string for?

Comment: @varevarao - without the first empty string, you would need to look it up as ordinals[day - 1]

Comment: @varevarao: the empty string is for the day zero :)

Comment: @varevarao: C arrays indices are 0-based, the calendar is 1-based.

Comment: Wow. Okay people I get it! :|

Comment: This seems like the way to go but I'm having some issues with it compiling... I'll edit my post with it

Comment: @Steve It should be `ordinals[t->tm_mday]`, not `t->ordinals[tm_mday]`. You can also move the declaration of `ordinals` outside the function, and make it `static`.

Comment: Yeah I literally just realised that, haha

Comment: Yup, just compiled and works perfectly, nice work my friend, thank you :)

Answer (score 6):

This works for all nonnegative `n`:

```
char *suffix(int n)
{
  switch (n % 100) {
    case 11: case 12: case 13: return "th";
    default: switch (n % 10) {
      case 1: return "st";
      case 2: return "nd";
      case 3: return "rd";
      default: return "th";
    }
  }
}

printf("%d%s\n", n, suffix(n));
```

Comment: 11st, 12nd, 13rd. Oh god my tongue!

Comment: Okay, fixed now with n%100.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a condition.

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char *suff;

switch (day)
{
case 1: /* fall-through */
case 21: /* fall-through */
case 31:
  suff = "st";
  break;
case 2: /* fall-through */
case 22:
  suff = "nd";
  break;
case 3: /* fall-through */
case 23:
  suff = "rd";
  break;
default:
  suff = "th";
  break;
}

printf("%d%s\n", day, suff);
```

Comment: 21th, 22th, 23th? That sounds weird.

Comment: @varevarao - By the time I went through 21th & 22th, 23th didn't sound that wierd.

Comment: @varevarao: Oops, my bad. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
void day_to_string(int day, char *buffer)
{
     char *suff = "th";
     switch(day)
     {
         case 1:
         case 21:
         case 31:
           suff = "st";
           break;

         case 2:
         case 22:
           suff = "nd";
           break;

         case 3:
         case 23:
            suff = "rd";
            break;      
     }
     sprintf(buffer, "%d%s", day, suff);
 }
```

Should do it. Note however that if you want to ever translate your program to another language, you may need to follow dasblinkenlight's suggestion, as you may find that the rules in some languages isn't the same as in English.